# how to delete a repeat row by id in a query, using QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring, jpql, querydsl, pageable

I'm stuck in get the query with unique row for codeRecurrence in a query.

```
public JPQLQuery<RecurrenceErrorVO> getQueryErrorRecurrence(Integer companyCode, Collection<SearchModelDTO<Object>> searchModelDTOs) {
    //Entities
    QRecurrencyEntity qRecurrencyEntity = QRecurrencyEntity.recurrencyEntity;
    QSubscriptionEntity qSubscriptionEntity = QSubscriptionEntity.subscriptionEntity;
    QRecurrencyDetailsEntity qRecurrencyDetailsEntity = QRecurrencyDetailsEntity.recurrencyDetailsEntity;
    QSubcriptionProductEntity qSubcriptionProductEntity = QSubcriptionProductEntity.subcriptionProductEntity;
    QArticleEntity qArticleEntity = QArticleEntity.articleEntity;
    QCatalogoValorDTO qStatusGeneral = new QCatalogoValorDTO("qStatusGeneral");
    QCatalogoValorDTO qrecurrenceType = new QCatalogoValorDTO("qrecurrenceType");
    QCatalogoValorDTO qbusinessTypeDTO = new QCatalogoValorDTO("qbusinessTypeDTO");
    QCatalogoValorDTO qcausalCatalogType = new QCatalogoValorDTO("qcausalCatalogType");
    //data
    JPQLQuery<RecurrenceErrorVO> query = from(qRecurrencyDetailsEntity).select(
            Projections.bean(RecurrenceErrorVO.class, qRecurrencyEntity.codeRecurrency.as("codeRecurrence"),
                    qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.codeDetailsTransaction.as("codeRecurrenceDetail"),
                    qRecurrencyEntity.statusGeneralValue.as("statusGeneralValue"),
                    qRecurrencyEntity.processDate.as("dateRecurrence"),
                    qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.transactionDate.as("dateTransaction"),
                    qSubscriptionEntity.contractIdentifier,
                    qSubcriptionProductEntity.articleEntity.itemDescription.as("productName"),
                    qSubscriptionEntity.numberDocumentClient.as("clientDocNumber"),
                    qSubscriptionEntity.customerName.as("clientName"),
                    qSubscriptionEntity.subscriptionValue.as("subscriptionValue"),
                    qSubscriptionEntity.statusSubscriptionValue,
                    qStatusGeneral.nombreCatalogoValor.as("statusGeneralDescription"),
                    qRecurrencyEntity.originRecurrenceValue.as("originRecurrenceValue"),
                    qRecurrencyEntity.value,
                    qRecurrencyEntity.status,
                    qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.causalValue.as("codeCausalValue"),
                    qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.causalType.as("codeCausalType"),
                    qbusinessTypeDTO.nombreCatalogoValor.as("marca"),
                    qcausalCatalogType.nombreCatalogoValor.as("causalValue"),
                    qrecurrenceType.nombreCorto.as("nombreCorto"),
                    qrecurrenceType.nombreCatalogoValor.as("transactionType")))
    //join
    query.leftJoin(qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.recurrencyEntity, qRecurrencyEntity)
            .leftJoin(qRecurrencyEntity.subscriptionEntity, qSubscriptionEntity)
            .leftJoin(qRecurrencyEntity.subcriptionProductEntity, qSubcriptionProductEntity)
            .innerJoin(qSubcriptionProductEntity.articleEntity, qArticleEntity)
            .innerJoin(qRecurrencyEntity.statusGeneral, qStatusGeneral)
            .innerJoin(qSubcriptionProductEntity.businessTypeDTO, qbusinessTypeDTO)
            .innerJoin(qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.recurrenceType, qrecurrenceType)
            .innerJoin(qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.causalCatalogType, qcausalCatalogType)
    ;
    BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.statusGeneralValue.ne(SirConstants.RECURRENCE_STATUS_FIN));
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.statusGeneralValue.ne(SirConstants.RECURRENCE_STATUS_SIN_CUPO));
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.statusGeneralValue.ne(SirConstants.RECURRENCE_STATUS_FIN_WITH_OBSERVATION));
    where.and(qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.statusRecurrencyDetailsValue.ne(SirConstants.ZERO.toString()));
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.originRecurrenceValue.eq(SirConstants.RECURRENCE_ORIGIN_INTERNO));
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.companyCode.eq(companyCode));
    where.and(qRecurrencyEntity.status.isTrue());
    SearchModelUtil.addDynamicWhere(searchModelDTOs, where, RecurrencyEntity.class, "recurrencyEntity");
    query.where(where);
    query.orderBy(qRecurrencyEntity.codeRecurrency.desc(), qRecurrencyDetailsEntity.codeDetailsTransaction.desc());
    return query;
}
```

this is my current code,
and this returns values ​​as the next table

```
CODERECURRENCY|CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS|STATUSGENERALVALUE|PROCESSDATE        |TRANSACTIONDATE    
--------------|--------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------
         16202|               14510|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-11-27 16:53:57
         16202|               14094|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:47
         16202|               14093|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:41
         16201|               14088|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:43
         16201|               14087|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:37
         16201|               14083|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:15
         16201|               14082|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:09
         16201|               14078|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:47
         16201|               14077|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:41
         16201|               14073|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:19
         16201|               14072|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:13
         16123|               13675|ERR               |2020-10-01 17:06:17|2020-10-01 17:06:28
         16050|               13511|ERR               |2020-09-21 14:11:31|2020-09-21 14:11:31
         16043|               13470|EXR               |2020-09-16 10:04:20|2020-09-16 10:07:00
```

Need one a row by codeRecurrency, I used code for remove the repeats rows, but works if i convert JpqlQuery to a list and this change the result of values show in the webservice, i need use pagination.

this code shows the use of the query.

```
private PageResultVO<RecurrenceErrorVO> findPagedRE(JPQLQuery<RecurrenceErrorVO> query, Pageable pageable) {
        List<RecurrenceErrorVO> list = Objects.requireNonNull(getQuerydsl()).applyPagination(
                pageable, query).fetch();
          Page<RecurrenceErrorVO> page = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(list,
                pageable,
                query::fetchCount);
        return new PageResultVO<>(page.getContent(), page.getPageable(), page.getTotalElements());
    }
```

I use this code for future exposure as webservice with pagination.

What I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use either aggregate functions with a group by clause (which cannot be used in conjunction with `query::fetchCount` in QueryDSL for JPA) or a distinct tuple with window functions (which requires custom functions to be registered). And even then you probably struggle with the entity projections in your projection. For example, you can't do `MAX(someEntity)` to get the entity with `MAX(someEntity.id)`.

With plain Hibernate and QueryDSL this cannot be done, but it can be done using the [Blaze-Persistence integration for QueryDSL](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration). Using this Hibernate extension you can use window functions or use `fetchCount` in queries that specify a `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause. You could also utilise Blaze-Persistence CTE's or subquery lateral joins to create the query.

Comment: I used at the end a view in the database, and create a new entity for the view and get data for work in the repository, i will check Blaze-persistence thx for your answer.

Comment: Yes, sometimes a view mapping to a native query is actually the easiest. I resort to them from time to time as well!